What propellant (coolant) mass is required for an actively cooled heat shield?
Stoke Space are using a regeneratively cooled heat shield to allow their second stage to survive re-entry. The basis of the design flows LH2 through the aeroplug, then using the heat captured to power the pumps to keep the LH2 flowing, before finally being exhausted out the bottom.
What I'm curious about (and don't know how to calculate) is how much coolant is required to survive re-entry. A Stoke engineer described it as "insignificant" relative to the amount used for propulsion in a FISO presentation. My intuition thinks that it should be around the same as the ablated mass required for an ablative heat shield, given that the principles utilized by them seem to be similar. I'm also curious about how it scales to lunar re-entry velocities, given the drastic shift in heating regime there and their lunar ambitions.

Interesting question, especially after the  burn-out of Starship's fins, Transpiration cooling may not be appropriate for the entire Starship, but it could be used for point cooling of the fin hinge area.

I don't see how it would be related to the ablative mass loss in a completely different launch system with a completely different heat shield design..

@DarthPseudonym What I'm trying to get at there is that the principles for how heat is extracted from the systems is similar; so approximations from amount used by similar scale heat shields can be at least considered.

When a spacecraft is on a reentry trajectory, its kinetic energy is roughly
$$E_k=0.5(8000{m \over s})^2=32 MJ/kg$$
All of that kinetic energy needs to be converted to heat to slow the spacecraft down. With a well-designed heat shield, such as the Space Shuttle's, about 90% of the heat generated during reentry will end up in the atmosphere (ref), and 10% will be absorbed by the spacecraft. You want the absorbed heat to go into the thermal protection system's (TPS's) mass (as the TPS is supposed to protect the rest of the spacecraft and its payload from heating up). So the thermal protection system must have enough heat capacity to absorb 10% of 32 MJ/kg. This works out to 3.2 MJ of heat capacity per kg of spacecraft.
The Latent Heat of Vaporization of Hydrogen is 0.44936 kJ/mol. Hydrogen is 0.002 kg/mol, so that works out to just
$$0.44936/0.002 = 224 kJ/kg = 0.224 MJ/kg$$
The heat capacity of H2 is ~29 J/mol*K, so if we assume that we raise the temperature of the H2 by, for example, 1000K after we vaporize it, that gives us an additional
$$29/0.002*1000=14.5 MJ/kg$$
Altogether we can store 14.5+0.224=14.724 MJ of heat in each kg hydrogen.
If all of the absorbed heat energy is absorbed by H2 coolant then, if we need to get rid of 3.2 MJ of heat per kg of spacecraft, we will need
$$3.2/14.724=0.217kg$$
of H2 per kg of spacecraft.
Since that extra H2 just added weight to the spacecraft we will actually need roughly
${0.217 \over (1-0.217)} = 0.277$ kg H2 per kg of spacecraft
(Note: You will arrive at different numbers if you make different assumptions. Consider this to be an illustrative calculation.)
I'm assuming here that it would be best to just vent this hydrogen. To burn it in the engines you would need to bring along extra O2 as well, which would add weight as O2 has a much lower heat capacity. If you tried to store it you would need stronger tanks which would also add weight.
Incidentally, you can calculate a rough "equivalent exhaust velocity" for the coolant hydrogen consumed during aerobraking by using the rocket equation.
$${\Delta}V/v_{eq\_exhaust}=ln(m_0/m_f)$$
$$v_{eq\_exhaust}={{\Delta}V \over ln(m_0/m_f)}={8000 \over ln(1.277/1)}=32,718 m/s$$
Now you can use this $v_{eq\_exhaust}$ value to estimate how it scales to lunar velocities. If the craft's return speed from the moon was 11000 m/s then its $m_0/m_f$ would be
$$m_0/m_f=exp(11000/32718)~=1.4$$
So in the moon-return case, the spacecraft would lose 40% of its mass during reentry by venting coolant hydrogen.
Ablative heat shields might do better because their bits can become white hot before they flake off, so they can carry away lots of heat per kg of ablative material. Hydrogen coolant cannot get any hotter than the maximum allowable temperature for the metal heat shield.

If that hot hydrogen is then pumped out of the base of the heat-shield, it acts as an ablative, providing a yet barrier that absorbs more heat that will never reach the heat-shield. There would also be an impact, probably slight, from it acting as a hot gas thruster to reduce the kinetic energy of the system

I made a mistake in my previous comment so I deleted it, but running 11,000 m/s through your original equations now nets me about 0.7kg H2 per kg of spacecraft and an "equivalent exhaust velocity" of roughly 21km/s. It don't believe the "equivalent exhaust velocity" idea is well-supported.

@JCRM Reentry heating comes from two primary sources: 1) Convective heating from both the flow of hot gas past the surface of the vehicle and catalytic chemical recombination reactions at the surface, and 2) Radiation heating from the energetic shock layer in front of the vehicle. Hydrogen won't block the radiation, but it might help reduce the convective heating if a protective film of hydrogen can be created.

and not only will the hydrogen pumped out of the base form a virtual ablative layer (blocking conductive heating) ,it can also form an aero spike (the other sort) pushing the bow shock away from the vehicle
